# Table View: Cannot subscript a value of type '[String]' with an index of type '[String]'

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to assign an array's items as indexes to get values from another array.

```
var indexArray = ["0","5","10","15","20"]
var textArray = ["Tom","Teddy","Mark","John","Samuel","Smith","Chris","Paulo","Simon","Ralf","Mizo","Karim","Lady","Coloy","Samantha","Maro","Kathren","Lyla","Jessika","Amanda",]

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    indexArray.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = textArray[indexArray[indexPath.row]]// here is an error Table View: Cannot subscript a value of type '[String]' with an index of type '[String]' 

    return cell
}
```

For more explination, instead of using `indexPath.row` as an index like (0, 1, 2, 3) for the `textArray`.

I want to use the indexes (0, 5, 10, 15, 20) from `indexArray` to be the indexes of the `textArray`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
cell.textLabel?.text = textArray[Int(indexArray[indexPath.row])]
```

Your `indexArray` is an array of string type of (integer) values, hence  `indexArray[indexPath.row]` returns a string value.

Now, array index always expects an integer as an index pointing to element in an array. So you need to convert result (string value)  `indexArray[indexPath.row]` from string to integer.

**More detailed explanation with sample example:**

if your `indexPath.row` is `0` then:

```
let stringIndex: String = indexArray[indexPath.row] // "0"
let integerIndex = Int(stringIndex) // 0
let textArrayElement: String = textArray[integerIndex]

print("textArrayElement - \(textArrayElement)") // "Tom"
```

if your `indexPath.row` is `1` then:

```
let stringIndex: String = indexArray[indexPath.row] // "5"
let integerIndex = Int(stringIndex) // 5
let textArrayElement: String = textArray[integerIndex]

print("textArrayElement - \(textArrayElement)") // "Smith"
```

Comment: Perfect.. Thanks so much. Good Job.

Answer (score 2):

Please update below line,

```
cell.textLabel?.text = textArray[Int(indexArray[indexPath.row])]
```